# Is it safe to use ASP.NET MVC3 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recently started working on an enterprise grade project using ASP.NET MVC 2 and the project is only 5% complete. I badly want to use the razor view engine but I am not sure if this is the right time to migrate to ASP.NET MVC 3 as its still a release candidate. What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your project is only 5% complete, MVC 3 will in all likelihood reach RTW before you have to go live. Given some of the relatively significant changes coming with MVC 3, I'd vote that if you can start there you might as well. Just make sure you budget some time to resolve breaking changes between MVC releases.

Comment: @shanselman just posted that MVC 3 will be released mid-January 2011. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioExplosionVS2010SP1BETAReleasedAndContext.aspx

Answer (score 1):

We've been using it without problems so I would say go for it, as dahlbyk says it'll probably be fully released by the time you go live. Upgrading from 2 to 3 is also quick and easy.